# How can I make a program use the public instead of a temporay IPv6 address?

Tags: windows-10, ipv6

I currently am and want to keep using the [privacy extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941) (Windows 10 default).

```
> ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Ethernet: 
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home    
  IPv6 Address. . . . . .. . . .. . : 2a02:8071:6a0:0f00:9801:dc53:2556:d8a2
  Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:8071:6a0:0f00:88e0:664:85c1:597a
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9801:dc53:2556:d8a2%5
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::5667:51ff:fea0:7156%5
```

However, for some outgoing connections I would prefer to use the public IPv6 address (`2a02:8071:6a0:0f00:9801:dc53:2556:d8a2`) instead. The curl call updating my dynamic DNS record is an example for this. In this case, a command-line parameter  allows me to use the public address instead of a temporary one. `curl -6 --interface 2a02:8071:6a0:0f00:9801:dc53:2556:d8a2 https://mySubDomain.nsupdate.info:mySecretToken@ipv6.nsupdate.info/nic/update`

But how can I make a program use the public address in general?

Comment: @Blaine The `IPv6 Address` is called `Public IPv6 address` because it should be routable. My Windows chose it based on th prefex advertised by my router's/ISP's DHCP server - no need to figure it out. Just as these whatsmyip sites, my dynamic DNS sees my public IP address as source of the TCP/HTTP packages - no need for much code there and it likely would be serverside anyway. Your comment indicates that my question is not very clear. Any ideas on how to improve it?

Comment: Well, technically both addresses are public. You just want to use a specific address. For a program, that’s as easy as specifying the desired local endpoint when opening a socket. However, most programs will probably not give you an option do influence their behavior when opening a socket.

Comment: @YAK - Your question is clear.  Blaine is simply confused.  Blaine's comment isn't that constructive, I can't determine the purpose, of making a comment that admits they have no idea how to help you.

Comment: @DanielB - Indeed the only way this likely will be possible is to compile the program itself, and change the the code to behave differently, provided the source code was even published.  I personally have not looked at how the program determines what the temporary address will be.  Perhaps somebody with more experience, can confirm, if thats a mechanic of the program or not.

Comment: Maybe not the most useful answer, but you could always just disable those temporary addresses. Then the software has no choice but to use the stable one :)

Comment: @DanielB both are routable, yes. But only the non-temporary one is called "public" in RFC4941. (1st sentence of my 1st comment doesn't make much sense nevertheless)

Comment: @Ramhound DanielB It seems like there is indeed only the option in the socket-api for applications and nothing on application lever for the os. Maybe for the reasons discussed in [rfc5014 Section 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5014#page-6).

Comment: rfc6724: "Implementations for which application compatibility considerations outweigh these privacy concerns MAY reverse the sense of this rule and by default prefer public addresses over temporary addresses.  There SHOULD be an administrative option (the Privacy Preference flag) to change this preference, if the implementation supports temporary addresses." -- Do you know if this preference can be changed for windows? (Hoping that browsers explicitly prefer temporary addresses)

Comment: @SanderSteffann True, at the cost of interrupting other connections (if you did not mean permanently). I was also thinking of simply using a portproxy, but neither netsh nor ssh allow source address specification

Comment: you can i some cases, explicitly set the ip address for some dynamic DNS services. I had a script for a defunct service that would supply that. You'd then just need to feed that in somehow

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Sure for updating DNS records, it is generally possible to specify the new address by other means than the source address and, as described in the question, for that specific case it is even possible to change the source address (when using curl for it); but I am asking for a general way (e.g. by setting an environment variable) to change the default address used by any (windows) program.

Answer (score -1):

Just disable privacy. But mind you, then all applications will use the one IPv6 address that is remaining. See https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/304071-ipv6-temporary-address-enable-disable.html

Comment: Well, the question states, emphasis mine: _"for **some** outgoing connections I would prefer to use the public IPv6 address"_.